# SQLGetStmtAttr output value for SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite, odbc

**TL;TR:** Is it correct to return success and report not an actual row number but other indicators like `SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN`?

AFAIK, not all ODBC drivers support querying of `SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER` attribute, so this attribute is optional.

Am I correct, that if a driver does not support it, then `SQLGetStmtAttr` should return this code?

```
HYC00 - Optional feature not implemented
```

Is it correct to return success and report not an actual row number but other indicators like `SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN`?

There are ODBC drivers that do that, for example [SQLite 3 for ODBC](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) does this:

```
static SQLRETURN
drvgetstmtattr(SQLHSTMT stmt, SQLINTEGER attr, SQLPOINTER val,
           SQLINTEGER bufmax, SQLINTEGER *buflen)
{
...
    case SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER:
    if (s->s3stmt) {
        *uval = (s->s3stmt_rownum < 0) ?
            SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN : (s->s3stmt_rownum + 1);
    } else {
        *uval = (s->rowp < 0) ? SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN : (s->rowp + 1);
    }
    *buflen = sizeof (SQLULEN);
    return SQL_SUCCESS;
...
}
```

Is this correct and kosher implementation?

[PostgreSQL ODBC driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/), for example, returns `SQL_ERROR` if row position can not be determined.

MySQL Connector/ODBC driver seems to always return `SQL_SUCCESS` and some value  calculated according to this scheme:

```
case SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER:
    *(SQLUINTEGER *)ValuePtr= stmt->current_row+1;
```

where default value is

```
stmt->current_row= -1;  /* Before first row */
```

I always thought that is reserved for `SQLGetDiagField` with `SQL_DIAG_ROW_NUMBER` identifier, as per the comment in ODBC's `sqlext.h` header:

```
/* define for SQL_DIAG_ROW_NUMBER and SQL_DIAG_COLUMN_NUMBER */
#if (ODBCVER >= 0x0300)
#define SQL_NO_ROW_NUMBER                       (-1)
#define SQL_NO_COLUMN_NUMBER                    (-1)
#define SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN                  (-2)
#define SQL_COLUMN_NUMBER_UNKNOWN               (-2)
#endif
```

Or, perhaps, the safest bet is to check value reported by `SQLGetStmtAttr(SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER)` against `SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN` too?

(The same question has been asked on MSDN Forums, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1430dabe-a5e9-4bae-967b-cd5b77bd800a/odbc-sqlgetstmtattr-output-value-for-sqlattrrownumber).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly valid for a driver to return

`HYC00 - Optional feature not implemented`

in this case if it does not implement it. A driver may also return 0 if the current row number is unknown or cannot be determined.

A driver should not be returning a negative number (ie `SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN`) as the type of `SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER` is defined as a `SQLULEN` (aka an unsigned number). The defines you've pointed out:

```
/* define for SQL_DIAG_ROW_NUMBER and SQL_DIAG_COLUMN_NUMBER */
#if (ODBCVER >= 0x0300)
#define SQL_NO_ROW_NUMBER                       (-1)
#define SQL_NO_COLUMN_NUMBER                    (-1)
#define SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN                  (-2)
#define SQL_COLUMN_NUMBER_UNKNOWN               (-2)
#endif
```

actually pertain to diagnostics, for when errors occur. You can sometimes track down the column and row that the error occurred on, or the driver can return these defines if there is no row/column associated with the error or it cannot determine the row/column.

The SQLite 3 implementation is wrong in this case, the MySQL driver seems to be correct as it is always capable of calculating and returning the current row number.

May I ask what the motivation behind this question is? Are you trying to build an ODBC driver yourself or build an app around one?

Comment: The deducation that a driver should not return `SQL_ROW_NUMBER_UNKNOWN(-2)` as it conflicts with the `SQLULEN` type of the `SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER` value is helpful indeed. However, I was hoping for a further reference to an authoritative resource. I guess, none may exist. I'm not developing a driver. I've noticed the different behaviours while using nanodbc, see https://github.com/lexicalunit/nanodbc/issues/71

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712631(v=vs.85).aspx for the `SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER` section, which specifies: An SQLULEN value that is the number of the current row in the entire result set. If the number of the current row cannot be determined or there is no current row, the driver returns 0.

Comment: Funny. Why the heck the read-only attribute is fully documented next to `SQLSetStmtAttr`, but not next to `SQLGetStmtAttr` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715438.aspx. Also, the ODBC 2.0 annotation is a bit puzzling. Does it mean rows are always 1-based numbered, so SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER 0 is before-first-row? Thanks for the pointer anyway.

Comment: The ODBC 2.0 annotation next to the attribute details is simply indicating it was introduced in ODBC 2.0. Additionally, rows are indexed starting at 1. I happen to work at Simba Technologies and have a pretty complete knowledge of all things ODBC, if you have the need.

Comment: I'm happy to accept this as answer (including comments which have clarified even more details),